# Impedir que salgan una lineas al capturar la excepcion en la consola

Tags: java

Tengo este método. Quiero que cuando de la excepción no salga las siguiente salidas si es posible

```
public String listarCriticasXNick(String nick) throws Exception {
    String mensaje = "";

    for (Usuario usuario : listaUsuarios) {
        if (nick.compareToIgnoreCase(usuario.getNick()) == 0) {
            for (Critica critica : usuario.getLista()) {
                mensaje += critica.toString() + "\n";
            }
        }
    }

    if (mensaje.equals("")) {
        throw new Exception("No hay criticas escritas por el usuario " + nick);
    }

    return mensaje;
}
```

En el main lo llamo así:

```
case 8:
    System.out.println("Introduzca el nombre del usuario: ");
    nick = entrada.nextLine();

    try {
        String mensaje2 = gestor.listarCriticasXNick(nick);
        System.out.println(mensaje2);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    System.out.println("\nPresiona Intro para continuar....");
    entrada.nextLine();
    break;
```

Esto es la salida de la consola

```
Elija una de las opciones
8
Introduzca el nombre del usuario: 
Pedro
java.lang.Exception: No hay criticas escritas por el usuario Pedro

Presiona Intro para continuar....
    at com.Gestor.listarCriticasXNick(Gestor.java:100)
    at com.Main.main(Main.java:165)
```

La idea es que las 2 ultima linea no salgan

y esta parte si se puede eliminar tb seria ideal

```
49541 [main] INFO com.Usuario  - Critica creada correctamente
```

La parte del 49541 [main] INFO com.Usuario

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que hace `printStackTrace` es mostrarte esas líneas, tal vez te interese usar `getMessage`, para recuperar sólo el texto que has definido al lanzar la excepción.

Tu código debería quedar así:

```
try {
    String mensaje2 = gestor.listarCriticasXNick(nick);
    System.out.println(mensaje2);
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.getMessage();
}
```